# NHibernate mapping multiple relationships

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

What is the correct HBM mapping for the scenario below?

I need to qualify `ValueItem` in the database as either an Income or Expense item in order for NHibernate to load it into the correct list when loading it.

**The problem is:** The contetns of the IncomeItems and ExpenseItems collections are the same when retrieving `Container` from the DB.

[image: Design]

**C#**

```
public class Container
{
    public virtual IList<ValueItem> IncomeItems { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<ValueItem> ExpenseItems { get; set; }
}

public class ValueItem
{
    public virtual double Amount { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
}
```

**HBM**

```
<class name="Container">
    <id name="Id">
        <generator class="hilo" />
    </id>

    <list name="IncomeItems " cascade="all-delete-orphan">
        <key column="ContainerId" />
        <index column="ItemIndex" />
        <one-to-many class="ValueItem"/>
    </list>

    <list name="ExpenseItems " cascade="all-delete-orphan">
        <key column="ContainerId" />
        <index column="ItemIndex" />
        <one-to-many class="ValueItem"/>
    </list> 
</class>


<class name="ValueItem">
    <id column="Id" type="int">
      <generator class="hilo" />
    </id>

    <property name="Amount" />
    <property name="Description" />
</class>
```

Comment: Looks like it should work, is it not working in some manner or what exactly are you asking?

Comment: @R0MANARMY, the problem is that both lists are populated with the same data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer from [Don on NHUsers](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/nhusers/wg5itr4D3rM/01Kks8vKMM4J) solves my problem:

Don's answer:

I have a similar mapping to yours, except that I am using bags instead of lists, I have inverse="true", cascade set to the default, I explicitly set the table name, I have different column names for each key, and I have references back to what would be your Container with unique names for each.  Perhaps it's the inverse=true or the different
column names.

Sorry about the hokey class names.  I changed them from the realdomain object names on the spot, and I'm not feeling very creative.
Hope this helps,

```
<class name="Form" >
    <many-to-one name="CreatorPerson" class="Person" />
    <many-to-one name="ProcessorPerson" class="Person" />
</class>

<class name="Person">
    <bag name="FormsCreated" inverse="true">
        <key>
            <column name="CreatorPersonId" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="Person" />
    </bag>
    <bag name="FormsToProcess" inverse="true">
        <key>
            <column name="ProcessorPerson" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="Person" />
    </bag>
</class>
```

Comment: This does work. However it isn't the most elegant solution. It creates extra tables for every single List. In a real database design there would just be a discriminator column.

Answer (score 0):

You can either choose an appropriate inheritance strategy:
http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#inheritance

Alternatively, if your schema can't be changed. You can specify `where` attributes on your list mappings. These will specify how to fetch them.

Comment: I thought of solving it with inheritance but that seems like forcing it it onto something that does not really require it. What would the `where` clause be in this case, there is nothing that distinguishes between the two items?  I can distinguish on the C# side but not on the DB.   It is possible to add a property with adefault value in the mapping and then where on that?

Comment: @Philip if there is no way to distinguish it on the database side, NHibernate won't be able to do it for you either. Remember it's still an interface to the database.

Comment: thanks again for you response.  I understand your statement. What I want to know if it is possible to provide a mapping perhaps something similar to the discriminator that is used for sub classing in NHibernate. With sub classing NHibernate provides the ability to 'decorate' the table further to indicate the type. Obviously I don't want to subclass here as it is not needed.  This is a common pattern and there must be a simple way of accomplishing this.   BTW I know it is an interface to the database.

Comment: @Philip, with subclassing NHibernate doesn't decorate the table. The table still needs a discriminator column that it uses to figure out the type. So if you can't provide a sql query to distinguish the Income items vs Expense items, then NHibernate won't be able to do it either. If the only way you can distinguish them is through code you can create private field that contains all items and public accessor properties/methods that are able to distinguish the items, add new ones, etc.

Comment: @Philip Fourie: You might benefit from subclassing in this case if you want to make sure that a record isn't taken out of the Income collection and then reinserted into the Expense column.  At least with income and expense, I can't think of a reason why such a transaction would be valid.  With subclasses you can make sure they are physically different types and code that attempts to do that won't compile.